# Dice Emulation - Concatentation of ImageButton Name for a for loop

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I am trying to write a loop to set the resources of 5 dice.  If I change the "imgBtnName in the last line of the code to any of the dice names (such as "dice1"), the line doesn't error. However, when I try to concatenate the name to fit the for loop, the following error notification on the setImageesource:

**error**

```
The method setImageResource(int) is undefined for the type String
```

Any ideas? I feel like I may be missing a syntax similar to the "int id" line.

**code**

```
public void PlayGame()  
    {  
        dice1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice1);  
        dice2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice2); 
        dice3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice3); 
        dice4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice4); 
        dice5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice5);



        begin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnroll);
        roll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnbegin);

        begin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random rand = new Random();     

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i = i + 1) {
                    int rndInt = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // Random number between 1 and 6                  
                    String imgBtnName = "dice" + (i + 1);
                    String imgName = "die" + rndInt;                    
                    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());

                    imgBtnName.setImageResource(id);  //trying use the imgButnName string to set dice1, dice2, dice3 etc to set the imagebutton resource
                }



            }
        });  
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your ImageViews in an arry and loop around them

```
    dice1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice1);  
    dice2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice2); 
    dice3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice3); 
    dice4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice4); 
    dice5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btndice5);

    ImageButton[] dice = new ImageButton[5]{dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5};

    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
         int id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
         dice[i].setImageResource(id);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  In case others also need help with this, I got it working when I reorganized your suggestion to:
`final ImageButton[] dice = {dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5};`

Answer (score 2):

`imgBtnName.setImageResource(id);`

I'm pretty sure that the String class does *not* have a `setImageResource(...)` method. ;)

In other words, you're trying to the image resource id to a String, not to one of the `ImageButton`s. I Imagine `dice1 ... dice5` are supposed to be in e.g. an array, such that you can iterate over them in the for loop and call something like: `dice[i].setImageResource(id)`.